# GraphQl Hot Chocolate Filter on List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I have an entity which I am querying through GraphQL which contains a property defined as a `List<string>`. This has a JSON Conversion on it so it is stored as a JSON String in the database but whenever its accessed is parsed back to a list.

A stripped down example of this is:

```
public class Area : Entity<Guid>
{
    public List<string> BreadCrumbIds { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Which has this EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Area> builder)
{
    builder.Property(x => x.BreadCrumbIds).HasJsonConversion();
}
```

I would have expected to be able to query this through graphql as something along the lines of:

```
areas(where: {and: [{breadCrumbIds: {contains: "4580473b-cf4b-45d5-8ea2-457015cb0e00"}}]}
```

But I get the error:

```
The specified input object field `contains` does not exist.
```

My C# query looks like:

```
[Authorize]
[UseOffsetPaging(IncludeTotalCount = true)]
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<Area> GetAreas([Service] Context context) => context.Areas;
```

What is the best way to resolve this so I can return the items if that list contains a specific string?

Answer (score 0):

Contains is not a valid search filter for lists.
You should make use of the 'all', 'none', 'some' or 'any' filter for lists.

As you can see in the documentation
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v12/fetching-data/filtering/#list-filter

Comment: if i change the query to be `{breadCrumbIds: {any: "4580473b-cf4b-45d5-8ea2-457015cb0e00"}}` then I get the following error: `"The specified value type of field 'any' does not match the field type."`. Banana Cake Pop also highlights the GUID String as an error with `Boolean cannot represent a non boolean value: "4580473b-cf4b-45d5-8ea2-457015cb0e00"`